# How to make a 3 in a row detection system in tic tac toe?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a tic tac toe game, I've implemented marking down the fields that aren't taken. There is a turn based system, which switches the players mark after one of the fields is marked. **The problem is**, I have no idea **how to detect 3 marks in a row or even a draw** (when all of the fields are taken). The fields are taken from a Node List and then pushed into an array called gameboard, I've done that so that I can access them easier.

What should I pay the most attention to so that I can solve that? How do I come up with an idea that's possible to implement?

Here is the codePen link: https://codepen.io/-E33/pen/eYbrbaM

here is the JS code:

````
const gameboard = [];

//player constructor
function Player(sign) {
    this.sign = sign;
}

//field constructor
function gameboard_field(field) {
    this.field = field;
    this.taken = false;
    let self = this
    //this functions was made so that players can't play in a 
    //spot that's already taken, it also controls the 'players turn' system
    this.field.onclick = function() {
        if (self.taken === false) {
            self.field.innerHTML = t;
            self.taken = true;
        }
        if (t === player1.sign) {
            t = player2.sign
        } else if (t === player2.sign) {
            t = player1.sign
        }
    };
};

const player1 = new Player('X');
const player2 = new Player('O');

let t = player1.sign


//push a gameboard field into the gameboard array
//gameboard array was made so that we can access the fields easily
for (let i = 0; i < marker_field.length; i++) {
    let newField = new gameboard_field(marker_field[i]);
    gameboard.push(newField);
    
};```    

I tried to think of how to make the fields detect the mark of it's neighbor fields
````

Comment: First, don't use the HTML document as your main source for the state of the game. Let `gameboard` be the *master* of the data, and let the HTML be the *rendering* of that master data. When you process a click, update `gameboard`, instead of setting `innerHTML` directly. `gameboard` should not be dependent on the HTML. It should be the other way round: you should first update `gameboard`, and have a function that displays whatever is in `gameboard` on the web page.

Comment: take a look at existing guides on how to program tik tac toe: [TheCodingTrain](https://thecodingtrain.com/challenges/149-tic-tac-toe), [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/simple-tic-tac-toe-game-using-javascript/), [some random blog I found on Google](https://dev.to/bornasepic/pure-and-simple-tic-tac-toe-with-javascript-4pgn)

Comment: @trincot thank you for giving me that explanation, I really needed it. It matches with what the course, that this project is from, wants me to do and how it wants me to do this. I really appreciate your time to comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "check_board( t, 3, 3 );" in the "onclick" function, immediately after setting the players marker and before you change the player sign. Where the 3s are the width and height of the board.

Note: Code only works with square boards.

---

```
/**
 * Check board after player makes their move.
 * 
 * @param string t the player characters
 * @param int width the board width
 * @param int height the board height
 * @issue SOF-77190125-1 Only works with square boards.
 */
function check_board( t, width, height ){
  /**
   * Initialize some variables that we're going to use
   */
  let index,
  length;

  /**
   * @var string selector Class name for the buttons
   */
  let selector = 'marker-field';

  /**
   * @var array elements_data Store the HTML DOM elements
   */  
  let elements_data;

  /**
   * @var array board_data Store the configuration of the players placements
   * @var array winning_configurations Set of winning placement configurations
   */
  let board_data = [],
  winning_configurations = [];

  /**
   * Check for error in board configuration.
   */
  if( width != height ){
    throw new Error( 'Oh! So sorry, the board must be square. :(' );
  }

  /**
   * Get the buttons, because we need them to know who placed what where.
   */
  elements_data = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);

  /**
   * Get the board data. Note: We're only storing this players data.
   */
  index = 0;
  length = elements_data.length;

  for( ; index < length; index++ ){
    let marker_field_data = elements_data[ index ].innerText;

    board_data[ index ] = '';

    if( marker_field_data == t ){
      board_data[ index ] = t;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Use the board data to create an array of would-be winning configurations.
   * Note: There may be some nice mathematical way of doing this with matrices.
   * @obsolete Requirements changed
   * @url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189783/how-to-make-a-3-in-a-row-detection-system-in-tic-tac-toe/77190125#comment136080110_77190125
   */
  /**
   * winning_configurations = [
   * board_data[0] + board_data[1] + board_data[2],
   * board_data[3] + board_data[4] + board_data[5],
   * board_data[6] + board_data[7] + board_data[8],
   * board_data[0] + board_data[3] + board_data[6],
   * board_data[1] + board_data[4] + board_data[7],
   * board_data[2] + board_data[5] + board_data[8],
   * board_data[0] + board_data[4] + board_data[8],
   *  board_data[2] + board_data[4] + board_data[6]
   * ];
   */

  winning_configurations = get_winning_configurations( board_data, width, height );

  /**
   * If any of the winning configurations width number of the players characters, then they win.
   * Note: We've updated this portion of the script to create the 
   * string that we're looking for dynamically. This is all a bit ham-fisted.
   */
  if( winning_configurations.indexOf( new Array( width + 1 ).join( t ) ) != -1 ){
    alert( t + ' wins!');
  }
}

/**
 * Create an array of possible winning configurations.
 *
 * @param array board_data A one-dimensional array of dense board data.
 * @param int width the board width
 * @param int height the board height
 * @return array
 */
function get_winning_configurations( board_data, width, height ){
  /**
   * Initialize some variables that we're going to use
   */
  let index,
  length;
  
  /**
   * @var array winning_configurations This is the return value.
   */
  let winning_configurations = [];

  /**
   * Used throughout the function to store configuration data.
   */
  let config_data;

  /**
   * Get the board data for the row wins
   */
  index = 0;
  length = height;
  
  for( ; index < length; index++ ){
      let _index = 0,
          _length = width;

      config_data = []

      for( ; _index < _length; _index++ ){
          config_data.push( board_data[ ( index * ( width ) ) + _index ] );
      }

      winning_configurations.push( config_data.join('') );
  }
  
  /**
   * Get the board data for the column wins
   */
  index = 0;
  length = width;

  for( ; index < length; index++ ){
      let _index = 0,
          _length = height;

      config_data = [];

      for( ; _index < _length; _index++ ){
          config_data.push( board_data[ ( index ) + ( _index * height ) ] );
      }

      winning_configurations .push( config_data.join('') );
  }

  /**
   * Get the board data for descending diagonal right win
   */
  index = 0;
  length = height;

  config_data = [];

  for( ; index < length; index++ ){
      config_data.push( board_data[ index + ( index * width ) ] );
  }

  winning_configurations.push( config_data.join('') );

  /**
   * Get the board data for ascending diagonal left win
   */
  index = height;
  length = 0;

  config_data = [];

  for( ; index > length; index-- ){
    config_data.push( board_data[ ( index - ( index * width ) ) * -1 ] );
  }
  
  winning_configurations .push( config_data.join('') );
  
  return( winning_configurations );
}
```

---

Here's some additional information that will provide some insight into how the get_winning_configurations function works. All of that arithmetic is calculating the array keys for the board_data array.

Calculating a row of board_data array indice involves getting the consecutive number values of any row, while iterating the width and height of the board. A similar idea is used to get the column wins and diagonal wins.

[Numeric values needed for an 8 x 8 array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlZwf.png)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I like the idea and how it's executed! However, I wonder what would be the solution for a bigger board that has more combinations? But once again, thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Updated to reflect the new requirements.